# bad display in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-chrome

I have problem with position of element in Chrome.

Site: http://isedo.pl/projekty/gladness/

Navigation to slider with team running down. But when click on link in header and other link on site  presses the element at a good place.

In Firefox is OK.

@edit

slider + navigate code: http://pastebin.com/ckPUeBaG
css:

```
    #teamSlider{
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
}
#snav{
    float: right;
    width: 35px;
    height: 250px;
    background: #818181;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
#snavl{
    background: url('../images/cnav_left.png') no-repeat top left;
    height: 48px;
    width: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#snavr{
    background: url('../images/cnav_right.png') no-repeat top left;
    height: 48px;
    width: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: OK i added html code on pastebin and css here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.teamSlider` is too big. It has a width of 3800px. This doesn't leave any room for `.snav`. I would make a container and then set the position of `.snav` absolutely.

Comment: Thanks, I have second question about this slider. Why <span class="simg">
                                        <img src="images/team/wrzosek.png" alt="Krzysztof Wrzosek"/>
                                </span> is last display element, if is declarate in above code as first?

Comment: @Piotr It's because you didn't use float on .simg but you did on the others. Float works differently than non-float. You can either float the image too or remove the float from the other elements.